# Create a Decorator Printing An Integer in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I'd like to create a decorator that prints units on a number.

```
money = 10
print(money)
```

results in '10 dollars'

```
money = 1
print(money)
```

results in '1 dollar'

I get that I need to wrap `money.__str__()`, but I'm not sure how to do that generically with a decorator.

Am I on the right track here?  Can the following somehow become a decorator?

```
def str_cur(money):
    if money == 1 or money == -1:
       return f"{money} dollar"
    else
       return f"{money} dollars"
```

Comment: https://www.thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/

Comment: @thefourtheye, it's funny I thought about editing the way you did and went back and forth on it.  I like your edits.  They are clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Decorators in Python apply to functions (and more rarely, classes), not to variables. So I think investigating their syntax is not going to help you.

It sounds like you might be able to do what you want by creating a class for your money that wraps up the integer. Your class can have a `__str__` method that includes the currency name along with the number:

```
class Dollars(int):
    def __str__(self):
        if abs(self) == 1:
            return f"{self} dollar"
        else
            return f"{self} dollars"
```

Now you could do:

```
money = Dollars(10)
print(money) # prints "10 dollars"
```

The `Dollar` class I wrote above inherits from `int`, so you can do all the normal numerical operations on it, but you will often get a normal `int` object back instead of another `Dollar` instance. If you want to only get dollars back, you'd need to write your own versions of the numeric methods, which alas is rather tedious (you'd probably want to stop inheriting from `int` and just have an integer attribute). If you only need to support a limited number of numeric options (like adding and subtracting dollar amounts from each other and multiplying and dividing by integers) it might not be too bad.

Comment: Thanks!  Essentially this implements the GOF decorator pattern in the normal fashion, and I think you're right that it is the way to go.